Short story about young boy bitten by a black widow
This was maybe 4-6 years ago. I read a stapled-together paper printout. It was maybe 30 pages total.
In the story, a young boy woke up one morning and got ready for school. When he was putting his shoes on, he felt a faint prick on one of his feet (this would turn out to be a bite from the black widow). He didn't investigate further, just continued getting ready. At some point during school, he began to feel ill and was sent home. A little later, he was rushed off to the hospital, where I presume he was treated. I don't remember if he survived or not.
What was this?
